# REST API - link to endpoint on the webpage

Tags: java, angular, spring, rest

I'am considering a scenario, where "files downloading" funcionallity will be implemented on the webpage (separate frontend (Angular) and backend (Spring)) . I am not sure, which of two possible ways would be better (and more professional):

**1. **Downloading files on frontend by REST API, when user clicks on a link****

`<a (click)="downloadFile(filename)">`

**2. Href to the endpoint**

`<a href="https://localhost:8080/uploads/{{filename}}">`

I would apprecieate any response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's discuss the advantages and the disadvantages of both.

### Using the URL directly in the front-end

**Advantages**

1. Very easy to implement.
2. Faster in terms of time.

**Disadvantages**

1. Changes in the uploads URL (`https://localhost:8080/uploads`) require changes in your front-end code. Hence, a new build has to be generated.
2. All users can access `https://localhost:8080/uploads` directly from the browser and download files that don't belong to them. Which is bad in terms of security.
3. You can hardly change the logic of your download such as giving a file a download name that differs from the file name.

### Using an API to Download Files

**Advantages**

1. You can control all the logic from the back-end and add extra data with your file.
2. If the location of the files changed the front-end doesn't need to worry about that. The only thing it cares about is to get the file as a URL or as a base 64 format.
3. You can strict the uploads location to be accessed by your back-end only which is better in terms of security.

**Disadvantages**

1. A little more complex.
2. Slower in terms of time.

In most cases, it's much better to get the download info from an API unless you had a strong reason to do the opposite.